# Как изменять принятую в конструкторе переменную в любом месте класса

Tags: android, c#, классы, ref

```
private class BtleScanCallback : ScanCallback
{
    public List<ScanResult> scan_result = new List<ScanResult>();

    public BtleScanCallback(ref List<ScanResult> scanResults)
    {
        //scan_result = scanResults
        //надо, чтобы изменяя scan_result, менялась и scanResults
    }

    public void f(ScanResult result)
    {
        scan_result.Add(result); //и в scanResults должен добавиться элемент "result"
    }
}
```

Comment: Никак :(. Только завернуть ее в другой объект.

Comment: а что ожидается от +=50 для списка???

Comment: в случае с `Add` все работает так как ты хочешь - добавляя в scan_result добавится и в `scanResults`

Comment: Попробуйте `out List<ScanResulr> lst` в аргумент. И тогда передаваемый список будет выхрдящим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В методе `public void f(ScanResult result)` scanResults недоступен. Его область видимости заканчивается ещё в конструкторе. Поэтому в других методах класса получить доступ к данной переменной невозможно, разве только к `scan_result`.

Но, если в методе `Main` при создании объекта данного класса в конструктор прокидывалась переменная, скажем `_sR`, то, после совершения каких-либо преобразований с переменной `scan_result` внутри класса, в методе `Main` переменная `_sR` также преобразуется. Достигается это благодаря передаче в конструктор аргумента по ссылке.

Comment: _после совершения каких-либо преобразований с переменной scan_result внутри класса, в методе Main переменная _sR также преобразуется._ - о каких именно преобразованиях речь? `scan_result = ...` - это преобразование переменной?

Comment: под преобразованием имелось в виду любое изменение(добавление в список, удаление из списки и т.п.), кроме присвоении новой ссылки данной переменной.

Answer (score 1):

Переменная `scan_result` - это на самом деле ссылка на объект в памяти (в данном случае на список) Т.е. если в конструкторе написать `scan_result = scanResults`, то в `scan_result` присвоится ссылка на уже существующий список. Таким образом, при изменении `scan_result` список `scanResults` тоже будет меняться

Comment: _при изменении scan_result список scanResults тоже будет меняться_ - о каком конкретно изменении *scan_result* идет речь? если этому полю присвоится новая ссылка переданный список не изменится.